# Having Eclipse automatically try to add imports on bunch of .java files

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I know I can open a given file, and hitting `CTRL + SHIFT + M`, it will add the import associated with the class I have currently my cursor over.

I'm making some big refactoring over my project and I decided to replace all the references to the `File` class to a `Filename` class of my own. As the system contains maybe hundreds of classes, this is being a nightmare to handle. I've replaced with `Search and Replace` all the references of `File` to `Filename`, but now I have problems with imports all over the place.

What would be the easier way to accomplish my task other than having to open all the files and manually add the import to the `Filename` class while removing the old import of `File` ?

Also, is there an easier way to replace a used class in your project (this case, the `File` class) by another one other than using `Search and Replace`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't do Search and Replace. Just select the classname declaration in the original source file and press `Alt+Shift+R` (or do rightclick and then choose *Refactor* and then *Rename*).

[image]

---

**Update**: If you really need to Search and Replace over the entire project or even workspace, then press `Ctrl+H`, choose the *File Search* tab, enter the keyword and then press *Replace* button instead of *Search* button.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't allow you to do that to types you do not own!

Comment: "If you really need to Search and Replace over the entire project, press Ctrl+H, choose the File Search tab, enter the keyword and then press Replace button instead of Search button." That's what I did. The problem with the approach is that you're going to get "false positives" sometimes, but I guess there isn't that much I can do about it.

Comment: Perhaps you used a weak keyword?

Comment: I've used "File " to "Filename ". But oh well, that isn't that bad.

Comment: Truly you'll get much false positives on such one. I by the way wonder why you would ever replace a class which seemingly isn't your own? Poor abstraction?

Comment: Ah right, poor abstraction :) Interfaces, interfaces, interfaces!

Comment: alt-shift-R, not ctrl-shift-R

Answer (score 3):

**Organize Imports**

You can right-click on the root `src` folder, select `Source` and `Organize Imports`. This will organize the imports for all classes and interfaces in the given project. Use it carefully.